# Apache NiFi: How to get files from latest directory based on name?

Tags: regex, expression, apache-nifi

I have folders with date as their name:

```
./20141002
./20141009
./20141016
./20141023
```

How do I get files from the latest folder based on the names above?

I know this command `find . ! -path . -type d | sort -nr | head -1` works but how do I do it with a NiFi processor?

Comment: NiFi provides `GetFile` and `ListFile-FetchFile` processors to ingest files from a file system. You can configure appropriate properties for the processor to fetch files with certain criteria.

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde But these only allow for pattern matching, how do I compare and get the latest directory

Comment: If you configure `Listing Strategy` property for `ListFile` processor then NiFi will keep track of ingested files and only fetch new files regardless of directories.

Comment: Have a look here for all the available properties for `ListFile` processor - https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.13.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.ListFile/index.html